# Как сделать обработчик нажатия на UI Button не только кнопкой Space но так же и добавить Enter

Tags: unity3d

Ситуация такая, имеется кнопка (UI Button) мне нужно что бы я мог использовать enter и space как обработчик нажатия на кнопку (UI Button), у меня есть набор кнопок (UI Button) по которым я могу переключаться только кнопками вперед или назад на клавиатуре (W,S или стрелочками) установленного через Event System, но не могу понять как сделать обработчик место OnClick, что бы кнопка (UI Button) так же реагировала только на Space и Enter, ведь по дефолту она реагирует только на Space на клавиатуре но мне надо так же и на Enter. Где можно добавить так же нажатие по кнопке (UI Button) через Enter, ведь где то же стоит нажатие через Space. Мне просто нужно обработать нажатие по кнопке (UI Button) с помощью дополнительной кнопки на клавиатуре Enter.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может в Input Manager можно где то добавить дополнительную кнопку Enter ?

Отлично просто сделали Enter это return, а Enter на NumPad это enter, что за чушь почему так не логично вот и весь ответ нужно было лишь понять что Enter это return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отлично просто сделали Enter это return, а Enter на NumPad это enter, что за чушь почему так не логично вот и весь ответ нужно было лишь понять что Enter это return. И поставить в Input Manager в Positive Button не enter а return.